# Unable to start server [3.5.3]

Tags: neo4j

I just download the community server 3.5.3 for windows.
I unzip it, go into /bin and execute the command `neo4j console`. But I get the following error :

```
AuthorizationMaganer check failed.
     + CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I download the version 3.4.12 and do the exact same things, and the server started correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. After some research I found out that for me the cause were some organization managed Powershell restrictions (basically restrictions by my company).
As it turned out, the ExecutionPolicy on my machine is set to RemoteSigned and cannot be changed.
As far as I can tell, the powershell command in the`neo4j.bat` executes another file called `neo4j.ps1` (the powershell file) and even though it has a signature block, it apparently does not qualify as RemoteSigned.

**Soluntion:**
I checked the `neo4j.bat` file from an older neo 3.4.* and this one has the entire powershell command inline. I copy pasted this command to the 3.5.3 bat file and it worked.
In other words:

- Replace `Powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0neo4j.ps1 %*`
- with `Powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "try { Unblock-File -Path '%~dp0Neo4j-Management\*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' } catch {};Import-Module '%~dp0Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j %*)"`