# How to install neo4j.bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd, neo4j

I am trying to install neo4j.bat using the cmd: neo4j.bat install service. I am following a tutorial on this so I can use BloodHound on my windows machine.

when running this command I am getting an Error:
AuthorizedManager check faild.
CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Has anyone seen this or know how to get passed this.

Comment: Are you running the command in an Administrator command prompt or a regular command prompt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782990/unable-to-start-server-3-5-3 might be relevant

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy folder anywhere `C:\libraries` and place bat file `neo4j.bat` in the created folder and add(append) the folder path `C:\libraries\` to `Path` environment variable

For adding environment variable,
search for environment variable, [image]

GO to `User variables for YourAccountName`, Select Path, Click Edit, Click on New > Paste `C:\libraries\` without quotes > Click ok > Click ok

Comment: I did as you instructed and tried running it the same way then also going into the libraries folder to try and run it. But no luck. I had the same error when I tried running it thorugh the neo4j folder. Then when I ran it through the libraries folder I got the error saying the argument path neo4j.ps1 - file parameter does not exits, so I added the ps1 file to the libraries folder. And I get the same error from when I started.

Comment: Don't ever place files or directories in the root of your system drive. Also never add anything to your PATH, it is never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading a differnt version along with the desktop version. This seemed to work.